# Mouse Handler in Separate Class not Working

Tags: java, class, mouselistener

I am writing a Crazy Eights game and trying to have mouse control added in.  I just starting writing it but I can't verify if it's working or not.  I've added System.out.println() to the pressed and released event calls but no output happens. I just need to get it working and be able to see an output of some kind for debugging.  I've also tried to use another example on stackoverflow to help me out but I'm still having issues. The below code is what I'm working with.  Let me know if you need to see another class.
Thanks

MouseControl.java

```
package crazyeightscountdown.CoreClasses;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class MouseControl extends MouseAdapter {

    public Canvas canvas;

    public MouseControl (Canvas c){
        this.canvas = c;
    }

@Override
public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("Mouse Released.\n");
}

@Override
public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("Mouse Pressed.\n");
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e){

}

@Override
public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e){

}

}//class
```

Game.java

```
package crazyeightscountdown;

import static com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor.addMouseListener;
import static crazyeightscountdown.CoreClasses.Constants.CARDPICX;
import crazyeightscountdown.CoreClasses.Deck;
import crazyeightscountdown.CoreClasses.MouseControl;
import crazyeightscountdown.CoreClasses.Player;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

//Sets up parameters for the game window
public class Game implements Runnable {

    private Display display;

    public int width, height;

    public Game(String title, int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        display = new Display(title, width, height);
        StartGame();
    }

//create the game decks
//Deck maindeck = new Deck();
    public Deck faceupdeck = new Deck();
    public Deck facedowndeck = new Deck();
    Deck tempdeck = new Deck();
    public int deckindex = 0;

    public Player playerone = new Player();
    public Player playertwo = new Player();

    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    public void StartGame() {

        //setup mouse
        addMouseListener (new MouseControl(display.getCanvas()));

        //set players
        playerone.SetPlayer(1);
        playertwo.SetPlayer(2);
        //set values to main deck
        facedowndeck = facedowndeck.SetDeck(facedowndeck);

        //shuffle the deck
        facedowndeck = facedowndeck.ShuffleDeck(facedowndeck);

        //hand out first deal
        FirstDeal();
    }

    public void FirstDeal() {
        int playerindex = 1;
        deckindex = 1;

        //deal each player 8 cards to start
        for (int h = 0; h < 8; h++) {
            playerone.hand.card[playerindex] = facedowndeck.card[deckindex];
            facedowndeck.card[deckindex].present = false;
            playerone.hand.card[playerindex].present = true;
            deckindex++;
            playertwo.hand.card[playerindex] = facedowndeck.card[deckindex];
            facedowndeck.card[deckindex].present = false;
            playerone.hand.card[playerindex].present = true;
            deckindex++;
            playerindex++;

            //facedowndeck.Truncate(facedowndeck);
        }

        //put card face up
        faceupdeck.card[1] = facedowndeck.card[deckindex];
        deckindex++;
    }

    private void render() {
        bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //Clear Screen
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    /******* START DRAWING HERE **********/
        //draw player1 deck
        for (int f = 1; f < 9; f++) {
            g.drawImage(playerone.hand.card[f].pic, (CARDPICX * (f - 1)) + (f * 5), 5, null);
            g.drawImage(playertwo.hand.card[f].pic, (CARDPICX * (f - 1)) + (f * 5), 450, null);        
        }

        g.drawImage(faceupdeck.card[1].pic,400, 200, null);

    /*********** END DRAWING HERE ***********/
        bs.show();
        g.dispose();
    }

    private void tick() {

    }

    public void run() {

        //init();
        while (running) {
            tick();
            render();
        }

        stop();

    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (running) {
            return;
        }
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (!running) {
            return;
        }
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}//class
```

Display.java

```
package crazyeightscountdown;


import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

//display parameters for the window
public class Display {

    public JFrame frame;
    public Canvas canvas;

    public String title;
    public int width, height;

    public Display(String title, int width, int height){
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        createDisplay();
    }

    private void createDisplay(){
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
    }

        public Canvas getCanvas(){
        return canvas;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your codes can compile? `addMouseListener (new MouseControl(display.getCanvas()));` looks weird since Game class is not even a JComponent, how would you expect it to override `addMouseListener()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the MouseListener to a component: `frame.addMouseListener(...)`

Comment: Changed my code to:   display.frame.addMouseListener(new MouseControl(display.canvas) ); with still no output